# find if reference object id is contained in the array mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to find whether a given EventID exists in the attendsTo array of a user. Is there any way to check for this condition in mongoose? Thanks a lot!

User Schema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add a username'],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add an email'],
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, 'Please add a password'],
    },
    language: { 
      type: String, 
      default: "English"
     },
    attendsTo: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Event' }],
    friends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    pendingFriends: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }],
    images:[{data:Buffer,contentType: String}],
    profilePic: [{data:Buffer, contentType:String}],
    status: String,
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
)
```

Comment: Any query that you have tried?

Comment: To return the documents that do contain a given eventId you can use
`db.userSchema.find({attendsTo: 'your_object_id_here'})`